# Embedding VLFEAT into python application

Tags: python, eclipse, vlfeat

I installed VLFEAT in my computer, I test it works just fine

```
    sift -h
    Usage: sift [options] files ...

    Options include:
     --verbose -v    Be verbose
    ....
    Version: driver 0.1; libvl 0.9.18
```

Now i want to invoke the command below from my python program, using `os.system(cmd)`

```
sift pic_tmp.pgm --output=/home/sara/data/pic003.sift --edge-thresh 10 --peak-thresh 5
```

But it doesn't seems to work, Should add something to my eclipse?
The source installation of VLFEAT to eclipse?

Any suggestions? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could `cyvlfeat` or `pyvlfeat` work for you? They are non-official python wrappers for vlfeat.

https://github.com/menpo/cyvlfeat